# How do I call a Go function from C code embedded in cgo

Tags: c, go, cgo

This is super basic, apologies for the rudimentary ask. I've got Go code, which calls a C function (embedded in the same Go package via cgo), which should call back another Go function. Calling the C code works, and the code compiles, but upon linking, the C linker doesn't find the Go function.

```
cpoc % go build .
# cpoc
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_goLogger", referenced from:
      _cLogger in _x003.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
poc %
```

cpoc.go

```
package main

// #cgo pkg-config: vips
// #include "cpoc.h"
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
)

// export goLogger
func goLogger() {
    fmt.Println("goLogger")
}

func main() {
    C.cLogger()
}
```

cpoc.h

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glib.h>

extern void goLogger(void);

void cLogger(void);
```

cpoc.c

```
#include "cpoc.h"

void cLogger(void)
{
    printf("cLogger\n");
    goLogger();
}
```

Comment: I think you have exports wrong—see [this](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-C_references_to_Go). I mean, the absence of the space character between the `//` and the `export` keyword is essential to make the parser treat it specially.

Comment: You are correct!!!

Answer (score 0):

The space between // and export caused the function not be exported.

<sub>Answer based on @kostix comment and it was correct.</sub>